# Starting with Android

Tags: android

I have installed all the pre-requisite to start android development.

1. Installed JDK
2. Downloaded and unzipped Android SDK and ran SDK.exe. Selected the SDK i wanted to work with.
3. Installed Eclipse.
4. Downloaded ADT and configured it for eclipse.
5. Created a AVD.
   6 Created a new Hello World project.
6. Set teh run configuration pointing the configuration to hello world.

When i run the application on the emulator, it doesnt give any error but also doesnt display Hello World. All is displayed is ANDROID and nothing else.

What could be wrong?

---

```
Console output
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] ------------------------------
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] Android Launch!
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] adb is running normally.
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] Performing android.HelloWorld.HelloWorld activity launch
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2010-08-14 11:40:25 - Hello World] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2010-08-14 11:40:29 - Hello World] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-08-14 11:40:29 - Hello World] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-08-14 11:40:41 - Hello World] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'android.HelloWorld.HelloWorld activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 0):

Was same for me yesterday. Leave it be, it's not loaded completely. After few minutes (don't know exact time, but definitely not longer) you will see AndroidOS home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Most times you run emulator it takes several minutes to initialize.

Try and create a "logcat" window in eclipse and see what it says.

If it takes too much, just close emulator and launch again.
Once it loads, please note that you normally do NOT need to close the emulator everytime you compile.